# Once I click the first check box then it will place check Mark in another Check BOX also

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to set the attribute of one check box to selected after I click the first check box

assume there is three check boxes

[] 1

[] 2

[] 3

if I tick check box 1 the second check box will also be marked as checked.

[✔] 1

[✔] 2

[]  3

I need the solution in In MFC.(Same Question is asked by some one but in different platform)

Comment: Show what you have tried. As it stands, your questions cannot be answered. There is just not enough information.

Comment: [CButton::SetCheck](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31deb72x.aspx).

Comment: I have a Dialog Box, In that only Three Check Boxes are present. Once I have Clicked One check Box, It will automatically selected 2nd check Box also.

Comment: @IInspectable,@ Michael Walz I did try the same way once                                                                                                        void CTask1Dlg::OnBnClicked()
    {
        int h = IsDlgButtonChecked(IDC_CHECK1);            
           
            
        CheckDlgButton(IDC_CHECK2,BST_CHECKED);
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `OnBnClicked()` is called when the checkbox is either checked or cleared. Your sample code gets the button check state, but doesn't use it.

Here is a working sample:

```
void CMFCDlgDlg::OnBnClickedCheck1()
{
    if (IsDlgButtonChecked(IDC_CHECK1) == BST_CHECKED)
        CheckDlgButton(IDC_CHECK2, BST_CHECKED);
}
```